# jQuery Validator with custom method

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am totally new to jquery and need to add validation to my form. I have a select box with 3 types of credit card options - Visa, Mastercard and AMEX. I also have a text box for entering the security code on the credit card. However, the security code is only required if AMEX is selected.

The select box is named "cardtype" and the textbox is named "securitycode"

So if AMEX is selected but nothing is entered into the securitycode textbox, I want one of those jQuery red errors to appear beneath the textbox when someone tries to submit the form.

I know it has something to do with validator.addMethod but would not know how to begin to add it to my main.js file.

Comment: You need to show the HTML markup of your form and the relevant JavaScript.  Please, if you expect us to help, put some effort into writing a good question, not just for your solution but for future readers.

Comment: Sparky..here is the html markup of my form:

select box:
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="cardtypeLa">Credit Card Type:</label>
<div class="controls">
<select id="cardtype" size="1" name="cardtype" onchange="enableTextbox()" required/>
<option value="">--Select Credit Card Type--</option>
<option value="Visa">Visa</option>
<option value="MasterCard">MasterCard</option>
<option value="AMEX">AMEX</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>

text box:
<input disabled ="true" type="text" id="securitycodeLa" name="securitycode" size="10" maxlength="255"/>

javascript next post. TY

Comment: the relevant javascript is simply what kanishka gave me inserted into the main.js file. Also here is the messages section. I have removed the actual messages between quotes so I could not exceed my allowable number of characters. I know where to put Kanishka's first block of code but am unclear where to put the call part. Does it go in the messages section?

messages: {
    name: " ",
    firm: " ",
    email: " ",
    cardtype: " ",
    cardnumber: " ",
    nameoncard: " ",
    expiration: " ",
    streetaddress: " ",
    city: " ",
    zip: " ",
    code: " ",
  });

Comment: The relevant JavaScript would be your call to `.validate()`, not the answer given to you.  Why would you put all the code in the comments?  I thought the nature of my request was clear.  **Edit your OP** with the relevant code so that it's helpful to future readers.

Comment: Is this what you mean?  

 var validator;

 validator = $("#formOc").validate();
 $("#formOc").data("validatorInstance", validator);

 validator = $("#formLa").validate();
 $("#formLa").data("validatorInstance", validator);

Comment: **Again, please, just read and follow -> [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$.validator.addMethod("securitycode", 
           function(value, element) {

                  var card_type = $("input[name='cardtype']").val();

                  if(card_type == "AMEX" && !$.trim(value) ) {
                          return false;
                   }
                   else {
                          return true;
                   }

             },    
             "Please ad the security code"
 );
```

If the card type is AMEX and you have not entered a security code value , you can not proceed.

in your validation rules , call the custom validator like

```
securitycode  {
                 securitycode : true 
              },
```

Comment: Kanishka...thank you very much. Can you tell me where I would put the call section?  Does that go in the main.js file?

Comment: you need to put the call section to main.js also

Comment: @user1742609, if you had shown your code in the OP, you'd not be having this confusion.

Comment: OK..Sparky, good point. First time user here.  Kanishka, here is the entire contents of my main.js file. I have added the addMethod section in your first part but not yet added the call section. I tried adding it in different places and when I select AMEX in the form, it does not give me the error message when I try to submit without entering the security code..so obviously I am not putting it in the right place. Looks like I have a limit on characters so I will just paste in a portion of main.js

Comment: Sorry...can't seem to add the entire code..so I'll just try to figure it out. Thanks Kanishka for your help.

Comment: @user1742609, click the `edit` button under your OP and add the code... as you are learning, you should not use the comments for this.